# LOAD DATA INFILE syntax error if executed from php or shell script

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, load-data-infile

I have the following SQL command inside test.php file to be executed by cron:

```
$sql = "
DELETE FROM `module_currency_rates_rate`;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/export/home/mysql/test.txt' INTO TABLE `module_currency_rates_rate` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
UPDATE `module_currency_rates_rate` SET `date_add` = now();
";
if(!mysql_query($sql)) exit(mysql_error());
```

When I execute this script via command line (all paths are absolute just to prove that there are no errors here) in shell:

```
/www2/bin/php /export/home/mysql/bin/test.php
```

I always get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOAD DATA INFILE '/export/home/mysql/test.txt'
```

However, when I run the same script WITHIN mysql command line (mysql-uuser -ppass), the files loads correctly and there are no syntax errors! I'm desperately searching for a solution to run query via php script. Just to add: all necessary permissions are given to the files and for unix users.

Comment: You can not execute multiple queries with `mysql_query()`. you have to split it. Also **STOP** using `mysql_*`  API. `Use mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: Thanks. This was the cause of the problem. However which API to use is completely different subject. In this particular case it was used to simplify the process.